# How to use a C file to create a Unix Executive file on Mac

Tags: c, macos

I use Sublime 3 for C programming. 
If I have the C file compiled in the terminal with gcc, it will generate a executable file with the .out extension. But I can't run it by double-clicking. If I compile it in Sublime, I'll get a Unix executable file. So my question is why the compiler in Sublime can create a Unix executable file but that the terminal can't?

Comment: I dont know about the sublime thing but in a terminal if you compile with `gcc programName.c` you can then run the executable file with `./a.out`

Comment: yes, I always do so. But I'm wondering why I can't run the executable file by double clicking the icon.@JackVanier

Comment: What happens when you double-click it?

Comment: It shows "Failed to open the document "a.out". The text encoding "Unicode (UTF-8)" does not apply.".@l'L'l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following `C` source file:

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
  printf ("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}   // from 'An Intro to GCC'
```

You can compile that into into an executable file with `gcc` like so:

```
$ gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello
```

If you now type the path and command name, it will run:

```
$ ./hello
Hello, world!
```

If you go to Finder and double click on that file, it will run in a new Terminal window.

*However*, if you instead do:

```
$ gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello.out
```

Now run in Terminal:

```
$ ./hello.out
Hello, world!
```

Seems fine, but if you double click that file in Finder, you will get an error since `.out` files do not have a Finder association with Terminal.

If you want to create a `C` file and compile into a file that supports double clicking in Finder (by opening it in Terminal), you have three easy options:

1. Rename the file `xx.out` to `xx` in the Finder. It will ask you are you sure, but once you do it should be double clickable;
2. Reconfigure Sublime to not use the `.out` extension for `C` files with `gcc`;
3. Create an [application bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(macOS)#macOS_application_bundles) (a folder in essence that has the double click action of executing the files inside in a configurable way) with either the Apple tools or something like [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus).

You *can* [associate](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22177?locale=en_US) `.out` files with Terminal. I don't recommend that for several reasons -- mostly that a file will work on your computer now but not other OS X systems that are not similarly configured.

Best of luck.